# Fconnect Button is not Generating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to generate Fconnect button in my web application to integrate Fb login.
Previously this code was working fine. but now its not showing me the fconnect button in my webpage.

what is wrong with this code. Or is there any changes to the facebook Api?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" ></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function () {
        FB.init(MY_App_ID, Domain_Path + "xd_receiver.htm");
    });
</script>


<fb:login-button length='short' size='medium' onlogin="facebook_onlogin_ready()" ></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Make sure there is no js error

Comment: There is no js error coming on the page.

Comment: That whole FeatureLoader thing is way outdated I think. Use the current version of the JS SDK, and embed it in the way the docs recommend.